# Get all data from GA into BigQuery

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am currently working on a project to pull data from GA with the "Reporting API V4" and export it into BigQuery but it seems I always have to define a combination of dimensions and metrics.

Is it possible to get all the data where one row equals one session and inside this row you get nested fields for all the pages a user has visited, all your custom dimensions Similar to what GA 360 offers for BigQuery (one you connect GA 360 with BQ, you get stream of data into BQ where one row equals one session).

Thank you for your help.

Charles

Comment: A long short answer, is not possible if you're not a premium user. If you are a standard user you have to do as you are doing, exporting the info into a SCV and importing to BigQuery, with the limitation that this carries.

Comment: ok thanks. I will start developing a solution with the API at the moment and will continue to look for a way to have a streaming solution to get all data.

Comment: Just to document @KemenPaulosPlaza answer: [Google Analytics 360 + BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/google-analytics-bigquery#getting_started_with_google_analytics_360_bigquery)